# Binary search tree in java, main is not reading from BST

Tags: java, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

Binary search tree not working properly, i'm stucked and have no idea how to fix this. Any idea what am i doing wrong. The object does exist in BST so why the error.any help would be much appreciated.
this is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation 
problems: 
    The method iprint(Node1) in the type BST is not applicable for the arguments ()
    The method preprint(Node1) in the type BST is not applicable for the arguments ()
at MainBST.main(MainBST.java:38)
```

code for my main:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MainBST {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {
        BST mytree = new BST();
        String file2 = "infile2.txt";
        String file3 = "inFile3.txt";
        addData(file2, "[,\n\r]+", mytree);
        addData(file3, "[\t\n\r]+", mytree);
        System.out.println("-------------Pre-order------------------");
        mytree.iprint(); //This is where i have the problem
        System.out.println("---------------In-Order-----------------");
        mytree.preprint(); //Object is there so why the error
    }
    private static void addData(String filepath, String delimiter, BST tree) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        File file = new File(filepath);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(delimiter);
        while(sc.hasNext())
        {
            tree.add(sc.next(), sc.next(), sc.nextInt());
        } 
    }
}
```

code for my BST

```
public class BST {
    Node1 root;
    public BST() {
        root = null;
    }
    public void add(String fname, String lname, int age) {
        Node1 NewNode = new Node1(lname, fname, age);
        Node1 compare = root;
        if (root == null)
            root = NewNode;
        else {
            while (true) {
                if (NewNode.age < compare.age) {
                    if (compare.lChild == null) {
                        compare.lChild = NewNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    compare = compare.lChild;
                } else {
                    if (compare.rChild == null) {
                        compare.rChild = NewNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    compare = compare.rChild;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public void iprint(Node1 t) {
        if (t != null) {
            iprint(t.lChild);   // left
            System.out.println(t);   // data 
            iprint(t.rChild);   // right
        }
    }
    public void preprint(Node1 t) {
        if (t != null) {
            System.out.println(t);   // data 
            preprint(t.lChild);   // left
            preprint(t.rChild);   // right
        }
    }
}
```

code for my Node1

```
public class Node1 {
        String lname;
        String fname;
        int age;
        Node1 lChild;
        Node1 rChild;
        public Node1( String l, String f, int a)
        {
            this.lname = l;
            this.fname = f;
            this.age = a;
            lChild = null;
            rChild = null;
        }
        public String toString()
        {
            return(" the age for "+fname+" "+ lname +" is "+ age);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mytree.iprint()` and `mytree.preprint()` expect an argument. You need to pass `mytree.root` to both of these functions in your main function.

Comment: I have an object (Node1 t). which should be passed into main and be just fine if i'm adding root then i have to send lchild, rchild and stuff.

Comment: so i did mytree.root.iprint(); and mytree.iprint.root(); and none would work

Comment: @JavaCoder It should be `mytree.iprint(mytree.root);` and `mytree.preprint(mytree.root);` and also, you need to make `root` `public` in order to be able to access it from another class.

Comment: now it shows this error:  [code]Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at MyMainIsMissing.addData(MyMainIsMissing.java:49)
 at MyMainIsMissing.main(MyMainIsMissing.java:32)
[\code]

Comment: @JavaCoder You can find more details about this type of exception [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2708186/question-about-inputmismatchexception-while-using-scanner)

Comment: @Titus Thanks So MUCH!!! i had entered a space instead of TAB. i'm so f****ing stupid.

Comment: @JavaCoder I'm glad I could help, good luck. Don't forget to accept Sneha's answer if his suggestion fixed the problem you've mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should step through the iprint function and find the exact node that raises the exception to determine the condition that is causing the problem.

It is difficult to give an appropriate answer because (I) do not know the contents.